# Display count number of images in carousel - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am looking to display the number of images with-in a carousel and which image number is currently active e.g. 3/5. I am using the following plugin for the responsive carousel:

https://github.com/mrbinky3000/responsive_carousel

I have looked all over for how to do this and have had no luck and do not know where to start as my knowledge of jQuery is very little. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is a link to an example of the code I am using for the carousel:

http://matthewtoledo.com/creations/responsive-carousel/example/example-1.html

Comment: Did you atleast try `var images = $('.inner', '.slider').length;`

Comment: What code do you have? There are multiple ways to display the carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the Images LI Container Position to the .slider-target Offset.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-mask">
     <ul class="slider-target">
          <li>
             <img src="img/01.jpg">
          </li>
          <li>
             <img src="img/02.jpg">
          </li>
          <li>
             <img src="img/03.jpg">
          </li>     
          <li>
             <img src="img/04.jpg">
          </li>                                     
       </ul>
       div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div id="count"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function matchimage() {
    var targetposition =  Math.abs($('.slider-target').position().left);
    var matchthis = targetposition;
    var visible = $('.slider-target li').filter(function () { return $(this).position().left == matchthis }).index();
    var total = $('.slider img').length;
    $("#count").html((visible + 1) + ' of ' + total); 
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to an example of the code I am using for the carousel. It is not hiding the images, they are contained with-in a masking div. http://matthewtoledo.com/creations/responsive-carousel/example/example-1.html

Comment: I am having a hard time to get it to work. I do not fully understand what is going on. What exactly is meant by var newLeft should be matched? I appreciate the help and apologize for being a little slow when it comes to jQuery.

Comment: @TylerAlmond  I have to leave for a while, when I get back, we can start a chat and I can try to help you through it...cool?

Comment: Yes, I am. how do I go about starting a chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19246/discussion-between-videsignz-and-tyler-almond)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to count a number of elements using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/qMeKT/

The jQuery:

```
var n = $("div img").length;
jQuery("#count").html(n);
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="" />
 <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="" />
 <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="" />
 <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

In order to display it like 3/5 or some such you'd need to see which element was currently active. Without seeing your code I can only image that the slider marks which element is active as it cycles through them. You'd just need to grab that and use it.